# RHEL9.3 + OpenLDAP 2.6.3 で pw-sha2.la をmakeで作成したがolcModuleLoadでロードできない

Tags: rhel, openldap

RHEL 9.3にOpenLDAP 2.6をインストールしましたが、暗号化モジュールのpw-sha2.laがインストールされてないため下記サイトの手順に沿ってモジュールを作成しました。

[CentOS7 + OpenLDAPにおけるsha2の利用 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/gzock/items/23dd7ed7ee886935d842)

文中の下記二か所を変更しております

- 1点目

  変更前: `./configure --enable-bdb=no --enable-hdb=no`
  変更後: `./configure --enable-mdb=no --enable-modules`
- 2点目

  sha2モジュールのコンパイルの際に `make` ではなく、`make install` にしております。これはsymas社のopenldapをインストールした際にpw-sha2.laが含まれていて、そこには`install＝yes`と書かれていたので参考にしました。
  あと、makeしたときにLIBTOOLがないと怒られたのでインストールしています。

上記の手順書どおりにコンフィグを `slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d` で再生成し、ldapaddをしようとするとldap_add: Insufficient access (50)とされるのでこちらは断念し、

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModuleLoad: /usr/local/libexec/openldap/pw-sha2.la
```

をldapaddしようとすると pw-sha2.laは/var/log/slapd.logで
lt_dlopenext failed: (/usr/local/libexec/openldap/pw-sha2.la) file not found
となりますが、
`slappasswd -h '{SHA256}' -o module-load=/usr/local/libexec/openldap/pw-sha2.la -s foobar`では正常に出力されます。

どこが悪いのか見当がつかないので、原因がわかれば教えてください。
原因でなくてもopenldapの掲示板や質問を受け付けているところが
あれば教えていただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Taichi Yanagiya様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
restoreconでロードできるようになりました。
機能等はこれから確認します。助かりました。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答に対する返事は質問に追記するのではなく、回答の下にあるコメントを使用してください。

Answer (score 2):

SELinux が有効なのだと思います。
SELinux を無効にするか、適切な設定、権限にする必要があります。

```
# cp -a /usr/local/libexec/openldap/pw-sha2.* /usr/lib64/openldap/
# restorecon /usr/lib64/openldap/pw-sha2.*
# restorecon -R /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
# /usr/bin/ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f (ldif file)
```

また、ldapadd コマンドなどは make install したものではなく、RHEL 9.3 同梱の方を使うようにした方がいいでしょう。
(環境変数 PATH を調整)